# How to get the PIDL of the Open/Save Dialog

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, com

I have worked on this question for a long time. Now I can get the PIDL of the explorer dialog from the code below.

```
::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, (void**)&psw)
```

This code can only get the explorer dialog, I found nothing in Microsoft's docs about how to get the Open/Save Dialog.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

CoInitialize(NULL);


IShellWindows *psw = NULL;
if (!SUCCEEDED(::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, (void**)&psw)) || !psw)
{
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}

long lCount = 0;
if (!SUCCEEDED(psw->get_Count(&lCount)))
{
    psw->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}

IDispatch *pdisp = NULL;
VARIANT v;
V_VT(&v) = VT_I4;
for (V_I4(&v) = 0; V_I4(&v) < lCount; V_I4(&v)++)
{
    if (!SUCCEEDED(psw->Item(v, &pdisp)) || !pdisp)
    {
        continue;
    }
 
    IWebBrowserApp *pwba = NULL;
    if (!SUCCEEDED(pdisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, (void**)&pwba)) || !pwba)
    {
        pdisp->Release();
        continue;
    }

    IServiceProvider *psp = NULL;
    if (!SUCCEEDED(pwba->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (void**)&psp)) || !psp)
    {
        pdisp->Release();
        pwba->Release();
        continue;
    }

    IShellBrowser *psb = NULL;
    if (!SUCCEEDED(psp->QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_IShellBrowser, (void**)&psb)) || !psb)
    {
        pdisp->Release();
        pwba->Release();
        psp->Release();
        continue;
    }

    IShellView* psv = NULL;;
    if (!SUCCEEDED(psb->QueryActiveShellView(&psv)) || !psv)
    {
        pdisp->Release();
        pwba->Release();
        psp->Release();
        psb->Release();
        continue;
    }

    IFolderView2 *pfv = NULL;
    if (!SUCCEEDED(psv->QueryInterface(IID_IFolderView2, (void**)&pfv)) || !pfv)
    {
        pdisp->Release();
        pwba->Release();
        psp->Release();
        psb->Release();
        psv->Release();
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Dialogs don't have PIDLs. What are you actually trying to do here? Where is the dialog? Is it in your process?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think windows manage these open/save dialogs, like I can use COM component to get all explorer dialog. "What are you actually trying to do here?"  I'm  working on a shell namespace extension project. "Where is the dialog? Is it in your process?" these dialogs are not in my process. for example, if I open microsft office and choose to open a file, I want to get the pidl of the file's address which user is browsing in open dialog.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is hard. I can get the pidl of file/folder in explorer dialogs with COM component, but i can't get anything in open/save dialogs. Do you know how to use COM component to get what I want. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There's nothing built in by Windows to get information from Common Dialogs (opened by apps) like you do with CLSID_ShellWindows. If you have a namespace extension, it will be loaded in each of these apps processes, so you can expose information using some IPC (inter process) mechanism of your choice.

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you for your attention, what your said inspire me, I have worked in the wrong way for a long time. I shouldn't do these things in the background program.

Comment: You can query the address bar of any Open/Save dialog using [UI automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). To get an idea what you can do, use Live Inspect tool from [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/downloads/). Everything in the UI tree that you can see in Live Inspect, can be queried using UI automation API. This gives you display name, which could be [parsed into PIDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-parsedisplayname).